# Charge Capacitor at 5V from 3.3V Microcontroller Pin

Tags: transistors, mosfet, capacitor, bjt, remote-control

I must come up with a circuit that is able to charge a capacitor to 5V that I can drive through a GPIO of a microcontroller running at 3.3V. The capacitor is in a different device and has a leg connected to ground. Of course I have a 5V supply available.

I have done some tests with MOSFETs but it looks like N-channels will not turn on sufficiently at 3.3V and P-channels will never turn off.

Maybe a BJT can be used to do the job, I have seen a few circuits but all of them seemed to have limitations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you connect the FET? No matter how insufficiently it is turned on, it should be able to charge a cap to 5V, if properly connected.

Comment: Draw your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how you might implement your circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYMRSi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Since in real life you will be driving M1 from a logic pin, rather than a voltage supply, you should use a resistor between the logic pin and the gate of M1, to protect the logic pin from over-current.

R2 is used as a bleeder resistor. It may not be needed in your application.

M1 must have a maximum gate threshold voltage of less than 3.3 V. It doesn't need to be a BSS138

The reason for using 2 mosfets is that we must be able to turn M2 *off*. If we were to use the 3.3 V from you logic pin, the "maximum" V_th would need to be between 0 V and  -1.7 V. There definitely are such mosfets, and if you find one, you could save yourself a mosfet. By using this circuit and a second mosfet, M2 only needs to have a "max" V_th between 0V and -5V. M2 does not need to be a BSS84.

You may, or may not want to have a current limiting resistor for charging C1, whose size has been left unspecified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the circuit looks fine but I'm trying to go the single-MOSFET way: I have Si2301DS (-0.45V), AO3401 (-1.3V) but they don't seem to be working, they are always on.

Comment: @SukkoPera double check to see that you are not accidentally using the drain where the source should be. That would account for the Si2301DS being always on.

Comment: @SukkoPera A single PFET solution introduces a problem at power up, where +5 V typically is available before the 3.3 V MCU has booted. During this time the capacitor may be charged accidentially.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Double checked and iring is fine, MOSFET turns off if I connect the gate to 5V.

Comment: @Jens: That would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't plan to answer my own question, but I've found a way to do this that I think it will be good to share.

Basically, instead of charging the cap when needed, I'm now keeping it discharged when not needed. Maybe this is not doable in all cases, but my particular circuit seems to work well with this strategy and it is nice because a single MOSFET does the job. It's even the same BSS138 which I'm already using in other parts of the circuit.

[image: newcircuit]

Thanks for all the contributions

Answer (score 0):

Single component solution:

Use a 3V3 to 5V logic level shifter, for example [74HCT1G125](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/916/74HC_HCT1G125-1541819.pdf).

When powered from 5V, HCT logic will correctly process 3V3 and 5V CMOS logic levels on inputs, and it will output 5V CMOS logic levels.

Buffer input: 5V.

Buffer /OE: 3V3 microcontroller GPIO.

If /OE is high, buffer output will be three-stated (disconnected).

If /OE is low, buffer output will be 5V logic high.

By using two GPIOs, you can also control the output between high, low, and three-state.

If you don't need the three state feature and want only high or low output, then a single buffer without three state can also be used as a logic level translator between 3V3 and 5V. You can also use an inverter. Which one to use depends on the state you want during power-up, before the mcu's code has initialized GPIOs.